# How to get table column values as Array using jquery in Protractor

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, protractor

I am working on a project, there is a table which gets created dynamically. i want get the column values from table as Array using jquery.

this is what i have done so far, but i am getting this error.

```
Failed: unknown error: arguments[0].push is not a function
```

code :

```
    var myArray = [];
    browser.executeScript("$(document).ready(function() { $('.table tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function(i){ arguments[0].push($(this).text());});});",myArray);
    console.log(myArray);
```

please help me.
Thank u

Comment: `Array.prototype.push()` is not available for string.

Comment: what can i use??

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use protractor's `getText()` method on `ElementArrayFinder` to get the value as an array. Try the below code.

```
element.all('.table tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').getText().then(function(textArray){
   console.log(textArray);
})
```

Comment: can store textArray in new Array ??